# jdk17 application not able to connect to sybase

Tags: sybase, jconnect

This application runs without any error with jdk8.

jdk version **jdk17**
**jConnect dependency**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sybase.jconnect</groupId>
    <artifactId>jconn4</artifactId>
    <version>7.07-27307</version>
</dependency>
```

**oracle dependency**

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8_g</artifactId>
        <version>12.2.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Error : *Could not load JDBC driver class [com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver]*

I tried by upgrading jConnect jar to *16.039-27463* and ojdbc to *ojdbc10 version 19.3* but of no use.
Did anyone face this before and how got it fixed.

Comment: JDK 1.7 likes the jConnect JDBC 4.1 driver - try to pull this one and place it in the same lib folder as your ojdbc8.jar library

Answer (score 0):

You need register the driver class manually.

Try add this code before start the connection:

```
 SybDriver sybDriver = (SybDriver) 
 Class.forName("com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver")
            .getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
 sybDriver.setVersion(com.sybase.jdbcx.SybDriver.VERSION_7);
 DriverManager.registerDriver(sybDriver);
```

Note: SybDriver from com.sybase.jdbcx.SybDriver;

Reference: https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc39001.0700/pdf/prjdbc0700.pdf page 6